# DataType Change from Varchar(30) to Varchar(45)

Tags: sql

I need to test a column which changed from varchar(30) to varchar(65). I don't have a access to insert a value into that column.Is there any other way so that i can test the column?

Comment: How about `UPDATE`? Do you have access to it?

Comment: I just have select permission on those tables

Comment: You don't need to ask the same question differently. You could edit your existing question with more details, instead.

Comment: exact duplicate of question #1753849

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server DataType Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753849/sql-server-datatype-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to put together a testing database and make the change there first.  Point your application at the test database and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

`DESC TableName` shows the table structure. Isn't that more than an assurance? :-D

Answer (score 0):

Use ["desc"](http://ss64.com/ora/desc.html) in oracle or an equivalent command depending on the database to describe the table. This will list out all the table columns along with their data types.